# How to use HTML5 cache with a image site?

Tags: html, offline-caching

I am trying to cache a site for offline view with HTML5's appcache manifest. The site consists of several webpages with one image each.

The problem I have is that I am trying to cache those images on different pages all together and exceed the quota available for caching.

Is there a way to make each page build it's own cache (not making it site-wide)? Which would be the best way to proceed?

Comment: I think the cache is assigned by domain. I'll take a look to see if i can help.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I was thinking of downloading the images only when needed (when the user loads its webpage). Maybe, that way, I don't need to download all of the images when the user first enters the site. Also, that would reduce the number of images that are cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use Cache-control Header from HTTP. That way you wouldn't exceed the quota and it would work on IE!

Be sure to set proper max-age, and public/private directives.

Comment: I'm not sure about information stored with cache-control headers being used by HTML5's offline feature.
Quote from diveintohtml5.org: "Some of these HTTP headers (Expires and Cache-Control) tell your browser how it is allowed to cache the file without ever asking the server whether it has changed. This kind of caching has nothing to do with offline web applications."